# how to find items in code coming from a specific package

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In Visual Studio 2022 we have the classic search function with which we can find a particular string of text in our solution. I'm wondering if there is a way to lookup all the classes inside a file that are defined in a package that is imported via the using directive.

Say for example i'm using package x.Business in my namespace `using x.Business;` is there a way to then lookup the classes inside this namespace which are coming from this imported package?

Comment: Object Browser? Not sure.

Comment: It's not a file, it's a namespace. Intellisense can help. Not sure right now if there's an overview or something like that.

Comment: Also try Ctrl-T instead of Ctrl-F. If search is what you want.

Comment: You can’t import packages (presumably nuget) with “using”. Please edit post to clarify whether you are looking for items in particular namespace or assembly or nuget.

Comment: ok i'm not too familiar with c# i edited the question hopefully it's clearer now

Comment: As logarr said you can dump the package in your project and intellisense will tell you what's in it. Of course, you can also use f12 or control+click to view methods or classes, so you can see which package it belongs to and what other things are contained in the package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think you're asking is... "In any class file in my own solution, I want to be able to identify which types used in it (for parameters, variables, etc) are from a particular assembly that is in a `using` directive."

I don't know of any tool that does this, but the easiest way to identify usages in your file is to comment out the using directive. Any types, methods, etc that exist in that namespace will turn red showing that they can't be found.

(By the way, now is a good time to learn the proper term for those lines at the top of the class files. They're called "using directives", and they're not importing a whole package necessarily, but rather a particular namespace. Not to be confused with "using statements", which are a statement you can write inside of a method that automatically handles disposing of resources.)